# Reference javascript array inside click function by dynamically creating the array name

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

So I have an array something like this:

```
var first_array = ['foo','bar','foobar'];
```

I am running a click function and trying to get the name of the array and loop through the array which has `first` as the ID name something like this

```
$('element').on('click',function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var arr = id+"_array";
    $.each(arr,function(index,value){
        console.log(value);
    })
})
```

Now the `arr` gives a variable name `first_array` and not the array. Hence the each loop fails. Is there a way to reference the array? I need to dynamically create the array variable name and get the array elements. I have also tried declaring the array globally and inside the click function but does not work.

Comment: `first_array` will be a string... You should use t as a key of the object...

Comment: And initial object should be: `var obj = {first_array:['foo','bar','foobar']};`

Comment: @RayonDabre And what if I have multiple arrays. Can I include all in `obj` like `var obj = {first_array:['foo','bar','foobar'],second_array:['bar','foo']}`. Will try it out.

Comment: You best keep you arrays in an object and access through bracket notation like myArrays[first_array] or if it is in global scope than access it like `window[first_array]` where `first_array` is a dynamic variable holding the array name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Rayon Dabre said in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36858477/reference-javascript-array-inside-click-function-by-dynamically-creating-the-arr/36858677#comment61284938_36858477), you should **use a parent object** containing your `first_array`, and more, like that :

```
var parent_array = {
    first_array: ['foo','bar','foobar'],
    second_array: ['foo2', 'bar2', 'foobar2']
};

$('element').on('click',function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var arr = parent_array[id+"_array"];
    $.each(arr,function(index,value){
        console.log(value);
    })
});
```

Comment: __parent array__ ? Do you mean `Object` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your arrays into a javascript object or a parent array and access them by key/name like `parentArr["first_array"]`